# One user of computer having trouble opening Excel file from Outlook attachment

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook, attachments

There's an office at work here that is shared by 4 different users (1 for each shift). They all have their own unique logins.

There is one user that is having problems where when she tries to open an attachment from Outlook, it comes up "Excel found unreadable content. Do you want to recover?" When she clicks yes, another popup comes up and says, "This workbook cannot be opened or repaired by Microsoft Excel because it is corrupt."

This is peculiar because:

1. The other 3 users who use the exact same computer (with different logins) do not have this issue at all. They can all open this same e-mail attachment the same way and Excel opens the file.
2. It's only excel attachments from 2 unique co-workers that are causing this problem for her. There are other people who send excel attachements that open for her.
3. If she wants to do a "Quick Print" option out of Outlook, it'll print it.

Any ideas?  This is all Windows 7, Microsoft Office 2010 products.

Comment: First step would be to restore the default file extensions.  There are numerious tutorials that exists.  Of course the simplest solution might be to simply create a new user for this user.

Comment: If the attached document is saved will it work then? If so, it could be an issue with that users Outlook data file. An Office Repair Install may help.